# Google Cloud SQL with SSL from Compute Engine and/or External Network

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm trying to connect to an Google Cloud SQL (MySQL instance using SSL. I've enabled two IP addresses and a user with remote access permissions from those IP addresses. I have also generated the certificate files from Google's Developer Console.

```
client-key.pem client-cert.pem server-ca.pem
```

Using this command from each of the two enabled IP addresses I successfully make a connection.

```
mysql --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem --host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --user=username --password
```

Since the MySQL client works I know my firewall settings, users, certs, etc. are set up correctly.

Now I'd like to make a similar connection with Java from within an executable jar file.

Following the steps outlined here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

```
Step 1: keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file cacert.pem -keystore truststore
```

NOTE: I substitute server-ca.pem for cacert.pem used in the instructions

```
Step 2: openssl x509 -outform DER -in client-cert.pem -out client.cert
Step 3: keytool -import -file client.cert -keystore keystore -alias mysqlClientCertificate
```

These steps create my keystore and truststore files. I associate distinct passwords for each of these two files as they are generated.

Here is the relevant Java code:

```
public void testConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException,
        IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    String path = "/home/user/dir/"; // path to keystore and truststore file

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",path + "keystore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",keyStorePassword);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path + "truststore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",trustStorePassword);

    String user = "dbuser";
    String password = "dbUserPassword";

    Connection conn = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://<databaseip>:3306/<databaseName>"
            + "?verifyServerCertificate=true"
            + "&useSSL=true"
            + "&requireSSL=true";

        Class dbDriver = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(
                "SELECT 1 + 1 as val");

        while (rs.next()) {
            i = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The MySQL value is: " + i);
}
```

Again, from both enabled IP addresses I am able to connect with the MySQL command line client with the same user and password being used in the Java code.

I receive the following connection exception with the Java. Given that the MySQL client works with the same user/passwd credential I am a bit suspect of the error message. How can I get SSL up and working with Google SQL?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:3988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1293)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at com.test.UserData.getConnection(UserData.java:81)
at com.test.UserData.testConnection(UserData.java:52)
```

Comment: Found the answer in the first solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509751/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-x509-using-jdbc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**mba12** I had the same problem, thanks for the answer!

So, the solution is here (as you pointed out):
[How to connect to MySQL with X509 using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509751/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-x509-using-jdbc)

I also found this one:
[importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i/8224863#8224863)

**Just for clarification**

`javax.net.ssl.keyStore` must be client cert + key combined, not just client cert as described in MySQL guide.

**To summarize**

1. We have:

`server-ca.pem` - MySQL CA certificate, can be downloaded from "SSL Configuration -> View Server CA Certificate"

`client-cert.pem` - client public key, can be downloaded from "Client Certificates -> newly created certificate"

`client-key.pem` - client private key, can be downloaded only from "New SSL Certificate created dialog box"

Described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance

Let's save them in **server-instance/** folder and create **jks/** folder for generated files in step 2.

2. Create `truststore` file

   2.1. Copy original JAVA's `cacerts` to `jks/truststore.jks`:

   `cp $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts jks/truststore.jks`

   2.2. Add MySQL Server CA Certificate / Google Cloud SQL Server CA `server-ca.pem` to JAVA's default truststore `cacerts` which we've copied in step 2.1.:

   `keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore jks/truststore.jks -storepass changeit -alias googlecloudsqlservercacert -file server-instance/server-ca.pem`
3. Create `keystore` file

   3.1. Convert x509 certificate and private key to a pkcs12 file:

   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in server-instance/client-cert.pem -inkey server-instance/client-key.pem -out jks/client.p12`

   (enter mandatory password), for example: `p4ssw0rd`

   3.2. Convert the pkcs12 file to a java keystore:

   `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jks/client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore jks/keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS`

   (enter same passwords), for example: `p4ssw0rd`

About conversion:
http://blog.ejbca.org/2008/02/converting-keystores-between-jks-and.html